# Does Flash (swfobject) can reject HTTP requests?

Tags: adobe, flash, swfobject

I've faced with web-based flash application. When I pressed some button in this app my browser inspector show me that GET request was being sent. When I copied this request as curl from my browser and try repeat in command line, nothing to happen, I mean no any changes on the web page in the flash app. How it possible? Does the flash app can make some affect to the HTTP request?

Comment: You cant load data (new information) into Flash from outside. Flash can be programmed to get the data (like on button press) so unless you press it does not `GET`. No its not affecting HTTP requests. It's not blocking anything. It just doesn't even know you did it because it doesn't work like that. The app is controlled by browser installed **Flash Player** plugin

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to inspect requests that **Flash Player** plugin send to the server?

Comment: If you have Chrome browser you can use from options menu `more tools`-->`developer tools` and that will show you network traffic (everything being accesed). The Flash app is listed as **type** : `x-shockwave-flash` and everything under that is a request by either scripts on web page itself or from the flash app. You'll have to know what you are looking for, check and decide if was requested by Flash.